# Json to Graphql conversion

Tags: java, json, graphql

I have a Json object and I want to convert it graphql mutation query inorder to invoke a graphql api.
So my requirement is I need to create a springboot project and expose a POST API which will take input as a json and convert it into graphql mutation query format,
then I need to consume a graphql api with the mutation query. Can any one please provide any pointer to it as I am not able to proceed.

Comment: @marktani, Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi David please be specific and post the code snippet you tried then only you can get a answer

Comment: Please post an example json

Comment: This is more of a project, and not StackOverflow question, try UpWork or some other freelancing sites

Answer (score 4):

Pass your object as a variable. You are able to put it in JSON format in the Graphql variables definitions.

If you look at the [official tutorial on mutations](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations), in the query, they pass the `ReviewInput` as a variable, `$review`:

```
mutation CreateReviewForEpisode($ep: Episode!, $review: ReviewInput!) {
  createReview(episode: $ep, review: $review) {
    stars
    commentary
  }
}
```

As the `ReviewInput` is, at least in my use case, a standard object from the model, used for both REST and GraphQl, the JSON can be directly pasted in the GraphQl in the corresponding `review` field in the GraphQl variables:

```
{
  "ep": "JEDI",
  "review": {
    "stars": 5,
    "commentary": "This is a great movie!"
  }
}
```

`{ "stars": 5, "commentary": "This is a great movie!" }` being your JSON.

So, in short, no conversion is required, you just need your API to put the JSON in the correct mutation template.