# How to convert JSON format of data to GraphQL query format

Tags: java, json, graphql

I have a Json object and want to convert it to graphql query in order to post a request on graphql api. Can any one please provide any pointer to it as I am not able to proceed.

```
JSON object extracted from the POJO:
{
  "customer": {
     "idFromSource": "123", 
     "title": "Mrs", 
     "dateOfBirth": "1980-11-11"
  }
}

graphql query that I need to hit a post request:
{
  "query": "mutation {updateCustomer(customer: 
                    {idFromSource: \"123\", 
                    title: \"Mrs\", 
                    dateOfBirth: \"1980-11-11\"})
                     {idFromSource title dateOfBirth}}"
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59577657/1776132

Comment: @Ash Raf you can use something like this https://github.com/dupski/json-to-graphql-query#readme

Answer (score 6):

Declare the input as a variable in your query. [Queries should be static](https://blog.apollographql.com/5-benefits-of-static-graphql-queries-b7fa90b0b69a). That means you never generate GraphQL code on the client. If you are doing that you are probably doing something wrong. I am not sure which frontend technology you are using but here is your query using JavaScript fetch:

```js
let json = // ... parsed JSON

let query = `
  mutation customerMutation($customer: CustomerInput) { # Adjust typename
    updateCustomer(customer: $customer) {
      idFromSource
      title
      dateOfBirth
    }
  }
`;

fetch('/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables: { customer: json.customer }
  }),
});
```

The trick is that there is a type on the GraphQL API (I have here assumed it is called `CustomerInput`, please adjust it in the mutation) that has the same shape as your JSON object. The server will therefore happily accept the whole JSON object as a value for the `$customer` variable in the mutation. No conversion needed!